# How change chart height and width into 100% from code?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I'm trying to dynamically change chart height and width into 100% from action script.
" chart " is ID of the chart... chart.height=100%  and chart.width=100%. Is this possible?. i did not find proper method to do this.

Comment: Using ="100%" can only be done in the MXML. To set this explicitly in AS you have to follow simion314's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are properties named percentWidth and percentHeight, set those to 100 .